# Postgres return scalar that is the result of a dynamic sql query

Tags: postgresql

This is a simplified example of what I want to do.

I have a function that returns some valid sql statement as text, based on the input of a integer id. These sql statements always return a boolean value.

```
create function query_func(_id bigint) returns text as $$
    select sql from my_table_of_sql_statements where id = _id;
$$ language sql;
```

I want to execute these sql statements based on an input id value and return the result as a scalar function.

```
create or replace function test.ufn_id_exists (_id bigint) returns boolean as $$
declare sql text;
        res bool;
begin
    sql = query_func(_id);
    execute sql into res;
    return res;
end;
$$
```

My question is: is there any way to re-write the second function that doesn't require the intermediate variables 'res' or 'sql'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get away with the `sql` variable, but I don't think there is a way to get rid of the result variable:

```
create or replace function test.ufn_id_exists (_id bigint) returns boolean as $$
declare res bool;
begin
    execute query_func(_id) into res;
    return res;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Yeah I couldn't see a way to remove 'res' either. Shame - thanks anyway.